# Merge txt files with pagebreak

Tags: r

I have a directory with .txt files in it, each containing a string of characters. such as `I am going to fly to New York`.

What I want to do is (1) read all files with R, (2) add a little text, and then (3) write them to a file which has all txt files concatenated and separated by a page break.

My code below does step (1) and (2).

```
files = list.files()
text_list = list()
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  text_list[[i]] = paste(files[i]
                     , readChar(files[i], file.info(files[i])$size)
                     , 'A LITLLE EXTRA TEXT FROM ME'
                     , 'A LITLLE EXTRA TEXT FROM ME 2'
                     , sep='\n\n\n')
}
```

For the concatenation with page breaks, I thought of this:

```
final_statements = do.call(paste, c(text_list, sep='\\newpage'))
```

If I run `cat(final_statements`), the separator is interpreted as string and does not add pagebreak.

```
"A LITTLE EXTRA TEXT FROM ME 2\newpagebf_99.txt


I have known her"
```

It's the separator that does not work here. Is there any way to get a `final_statements` file that I can write to a txt, pdf, doc (doesn't matter which format), where the elements of `text_list` are separated by a page break?
This would save a lot of time-consuming manual work.

Comment: What does you mean when you say the separator doesn't work? That you can't see the page break? What happens when you run `cat(text_list)` after your loop?

Comment: Also, `file.info` doesn't really need to be in a loop, it can be vectorised by just passing `files` as the first argument. You will get file information for all of the files in one call.

Comment: @OliverFrost I've added output with `cat`. I'm looking for some way (maybe not through the paste function after all) to merge the text files with a pagebreak, so that they will (physically) print on different pages later.